# Rails: Restful Authentication Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, restful-authentication

I have two applications that use same database. Let's call them Site and API. I'm using Restful Authentication for user management.

If I create a user from "Site" this user doesn't work when try to login from API and vise versa. I can see the records are being saved in the same table.

Am I missing something? It should work?

Comment: error description, log files and maybe even code would greatly help

Comment: Are the actual logins failing or are you expecting the user to be logged in to the other side automatically?  Are both of these sites sharing the shame hostname or different hostnames?

Comment: I'm on localhost. If I create user account on Site A, It works on site A, but when I tried to login on Site B (API) it fails and vise versa. Using same database for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Rails 3.

In your initializers/site_keys.rb REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY should be the same in your both applications then authentication will work properly in your both applications.